# How do I lock the read on a MAX() value with Doctrine?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, locking

I have a table where, when writing new rows, I get the value of `MAX(grouping_id)` and add one. I then save a bunch of rows with the same `grouping_id` value. The issue is that  I have a few collisions in the `grouping_id`. Two sets of separate data have read the same value from `MAX()`. My code looks like this:

```
    $em->transactional(function($em) use ($data) {
        $max_grouping_id = $em->getRepository('FormData')
            ->createQueryBuilder('fd')
            ->select('MAX(fd.grouping_id)')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getSingleScalarResult()
        ;

        settype($max_grouping_id, 'int');
        $grouping_id = $max_grouping_id+1;

        foreach($data as $formdata) {
            $formdata->setGroupingId($grouping_id);
            $em->persist($formdata);
        }
    });

    try {
        $em->flush();
    } catch(\Exception $e) {
        return $this->redirect(/* */);
    }
```

I've already set all other data for the `$formdata` entities.

So somehow I need to lock the read on the value of `MAX(fd.grouping_id)` so that a concurrent request will not be able to read the value until I've completed flushing the formdata entities. But is it possible to lock a calculated value? The database is MySQL InnoDB.

I have only had very few collisions, but they are there never the less.

Comment: Also other suggested solutions to work around collisions are appreciated. Maybe adding a random hash along with the `grouping_id` or instead of it.

Comment: Why don't use an auto-incremented id?

Comment: I need several rows with the same `grouping_id`. The primary key (not grouping_id) is auto incremented, I guess if it's possible to have two auto incrementing columns with Doctrine/MySQL then I could first persist one row and then the rest. Would it increment correctly with the previous increment value existing several times?

Comment: Ok. I don't know about two incerementing columns, sorry. Maybe you can use a `Group` entity with a ManyToOne relation in order to manage your groups.